# Where is the implementation for /proc/net/wireless in the kernel source

Tags: linux-kernel

I want to know where in the kernel source tree is /proc/net/wireless implemented so I could look at its implementation to get an idea how Quality link level noise parameters are populated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's implemented in net/wireless/wext-proc.c, especially see
`wireless_dev_seq_show()` function:

```c
static int wireless_dev_seq_show(struct seq_file *seq, void *v)
{
    might_sleep();

    if (v == SEQ_START_TOKEN)
        seq_printf(seq, "Inter-| sta-|   Quality        |   Discarded "
                "packets               | Missed | WE\n"
                " face | tus | link level noise |  nwid  "
                "crypt   frag  retry   misc | beacon | %d\n",
               WIRELESS_EXT);
    else
        wireless_seq_printf_stats(seq, v);
    return 0;
}
```

Furthermore, call stack is `wireless_seq_printf_stats()` -> `get_wireless_stats()` -> `dev->ieee80211_ptr->wiphy->wext->get_wireless_stats(dev)` and from here implementation depends on the given chip, for example `.get_wireless_stats = airo_get_wireless_stats` in drivers/net/wireless/cisco/airo.c

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The values seem to be coming from struct seq_file *m data structure is there a way to know which function populates this structure with the values of Quality link level and noise?

Comment: `wireless_seq_printf_stats()` -> `get_wireless_stats()` -> `dev->ieee80211_ptr->wiphy->wext->get_wireless_stats(dev)` and from here implementation depends on the given chip, for example `.get_wireless_stats = airo_get_wireless_stats` in `drivers/net/wireless/cisco/airo.c`.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted, Thanks a lot

Comment: If you like this answer please mark it as solved to let other users
know your problem is solved. Also see [What should I do when someone
answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: sure i'll do that